# Verb agreement in past tense?

Tags: verbs

Is it correct to say "I **told** you he **would cry** when he **saw** you"? or "I **told you** he **would cry** when he **sees** you"?

Comment: We *usually* backshift the main verb of the "indirectly reported speech" clause - as in *He told me his name **was** Smith*. And in your example we'd normally extend that principle to the verb in the additional clause ***when he saw you***, simply for superficial consistency. But that doesn't imply ***when he sees you*** is "wrong". Personally, I might actually *prefer* your second version (even with the "jumbled" tenses" ) if the person was actually present and crying ***at time of speaking***.

Answer (score 0):

*would* can be used in both the past and the present/future

- I thought Iceland *would* win the World Cup
- It *would* be good if May solves the Brexit problem

So you have to consider what you mean here:

- I told you he *would* cry when he *saw* you (which he did when he saw you yesterday)
- I told you he *would* cry when he *sees* you (which he does every time he sees you)

In situations where the tense is not clear, where his name *was* Smith and it *still is*, we have a generalization. This is normally put in the present in a simple sentence in English and we tend to backshift as @FumbleFingers discusses.